# Data fetching time is very slow in locally and server

Tags: mysql, database

i am using MySQL database, i try fetch fetch some data in 200000 data s

**my query**

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('admission');
$this->db->where('ad_no NOT IN (select ad_no from payment where date >= date_add(curdate(), interval -'.$opt.' day))');
$this->db->where('bal_fees >',0 );
$this->db->order_by("admission.ad_no", "desc");
$this->db->limit(1000); 
$query = $this->db->get();  
return $query->result() ;
```

**$opt** is *30* or *15* !!!

and my table structure is 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnvSH.png)

the result show in tcp pdf
any way to fetch fast?please help me!!
thanks in advance!!

Comment: Review your table and provide indexes.

Comment: i will show the table full image

Comment: Please edit and add table schema as part of question.

Comment: ok @manoj kumar

Comment: i am using codeigniter but in core php the date fetch fastly

Comment: Please post results of 
  SHOW INDEX FROM admission;
  SHOW INDEX FROM payment;
in your question.

Comment: $res=mysql_query("select * from admission where ad_no not in (select ad_no from payment where date >= date_add(curdate(), interval -$opt day)) and bal_fees>0 order by ad_no asc ");    , this core php using query this work fastly  why ? why that query work very slow in codeigniter

Comment: @Wilson Hauck   
i will set index for that field in mysql but the result show very very slow why?

Comment: @shambu  Please post results of SHOW INDEX FROM admission; and SHOW INDEX FROM payment; in your question.   With this information we will see Cardinality and other needed details about your indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please consider adding indexes on:
1. ad_no   (index not needed if its primary key)
2. bal_fees
3. ad_date

Comment: i will set index for that field in mysql but the result show very very slow why?change the query?

Comment: the issue in print the result as a pdf in tcp pdf ,the query limit as 1000 that reduce to 250 print pdf fastly